# How to get solution path from greedy algorithm?

Tags: python, computer-science, greedy

I have greedy algoithm with job scheduling problem, but I want to return **which one projects were chosen** to get this max value, how can I do that?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import date


@dataclass
class InvestmentProject:
    profit: int
    begin_date: date
    end_date: date


def get_max_sequence(arr, i=0):
    if i == len(arr):
        return 0
    j = i + 1
    while j < len(arr) and arr[i].end_date > arr[j].begin_date:
        j += 1
    one = arr[i].profit + get_max_sequence(arr, j)
    two = get_max_sequence(arr, i+1)
    return max(one, two)


def main():
    arr = [
        InvestmentProject(30, date(2022, 10, 10), date(2022, 10, 14)),
        InvestmentProject(15, date(2022, 10, 15), date(2022, 10, 16)),
        InvestmentProject(25, date(2022, 10, 12), date(2022, 10, 15)),
        InvestmentProject(10, date(2022, 10, 20), date(2022, 10, 26)),
    ]
    print(get_max_sequence(sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x.begin_date)))
```

Comment: rewrite your ```get_max_sequence``` function to return the InvestmentProject rather than just the value

Comment: yes, but how can I rewrite it? It's harder because of recursion

Comment: This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with.

Comment: maybe you should return list with indexes, `return 0, []` and later always use `val, indexes = get_max_sequence(...)` and calculate new value on `val` and add new index to `indexes`, later calculate `result max()` and later `return val, indexes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always return value and list of indexes.

First

```
if i == len(arr):
   return 0, []
```

Next you would have to always get value and list before calculations

```
    val, indexes = get_max_sequence(arr, j)

    one = arr[i].profit + val
    
    two, other_indexes = get_max_sequence(arr, i+1)
```

And you would have to manually check `max()`

```
    if one > two:
        return one, indexes + [i]
    else:
        return two, other_indexes
```

---

Minimal working code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import date


@dataclass
class InvestmentProject:
    profit: int
    begin_date: date
    end_date: date


def get_max_sequence(arr, i=0):
    if i == len(arr):
        return 0, []
    
    j = i + 1
    while j < len(arr) and arr[i].end_date > arr[j].begin_date:
        j += 1
        
    val, indexes = get_max_sequence(arr, j)
    one = arr[i].profit + val
    
    two, other_indexes = get_max_sequence(arr, i+1)
    
    if one > two:
        print('one:', indexes+[i])
        return one, indexes + [i]
    else:
        print('two:', other_indexes)
        return two, other_indexes


def main():
    arr = [
        InvestmentProject(30, date(2022, 10, 10), date(2022, 10, 14)),
        InvestmentProject(15, date(2022, 10, 15), date(2022, 10, 16)),
        InvestmentProject(25, date(2022, 10, 12), date(2022, 10, 15)),
        InvestmentProject(10, date(2022, 10, 20), date(2022, 10, 26)),
    ]
    
    arr = list(sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x.begin_date))
    for item in arr:
        print(item)
    print(get_max_sequence(arr))
    
main()
```